# Edit textbox of gridview cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

I have a gridview having two columns name and address and a save button.
Its a autogenerated column grid.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStandardSummary" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="columnheaderLightBlue"
                                            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="infoarea" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                            AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gvStandardSummary_PageIndexChanged"
                                            OnRowDataBound="gvStandardSummary_OnRowDataBound" EmptyDataText="No work items to display."
                                            EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="infoarea" OnRowCommand="gvStaffingPlan_RowCommand">

                                        </asp:GridView>
```

I cannot use Item template.I need a inline edit for address column only .

when i click on address field it will become editable ...i will edit ...then click second record address edit  ...and finally save it ..

On saving it should update database and Reload.I can not use item templete and have to add textbox in Rowdaabound ...but nneed the exact solution ...Any help

In Row data boung i am adding a textbox

```
TextBox txtAddress = new TextBox();
                txtAddress.ReadOnly = false;
                e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txtAddress);
                e.Row.Cells[1].Style.Add("text-align", "center");
```

Here how can i auto fit it in cell ...and Make it editable

because i am not using Wrapping here

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space:nowrap;");


                        }
```

Columns should be expand and collapse based on texts
                        txtpkgNumber.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detail? Are you using default ASP.NET Grid View edit, i.e. only one row edit at a time? Or are you trying to be able to edit all rows on the click of a button?

Comment: @Nunners Its one row edit at a time.Normal ASP.net Gridviw...here i can add a text box in Rowdatabound...but need to Auto fit that text box in Cell ..

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why you need to add the TextBox in the RowDataBound method? And what exactly are you having trouble with? The Update? The TextBox being added?

Answer (score 0):

Use the EditItemTemplate Of gridview for editing

refer

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx
http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/07/bindsaveeditupdatecanceldeletepaging.html#.UkLRgoZi3BE
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f0ae2/gridview-edit-delete-and-update-in-Asp-Net/